# Using Python Add 80 directories with 6 subdirectories?

Tags: python, operating-system, windows-10

I am trying to add 80 subdirectories within a given directory.

Each directory needs the following sub directories:

```
app docs
chk shts
le docs
recon
set-up docs
timeline
```

I have an Excel file that I use for the primary directories that works for those, but how do I add the subdirectories?

The code that I use for the client directories are as follows:

```
import os
import pyexcel as pe
import pyexcel_xlsx

client = 'LAM'
spath = r'c:\Users\Ryan *****\OneDrive - L******y \Desktop\clientStructure\Team \%s' %(client)
fpath = r"c:\Users\Ryan *****\OneDrive - L******y \Desktop\testtesttest.xlsx"
data = pe.get_array(file_name=fpath)
folders =[]
for i in data:
    folders.extend(i)

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(spath))
except:
    for folder in folders:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(spath, str(folder)))

print('Done')
```

Comment: You question has almost nothing to do with pyexcel, so I suggest you [edit] it and provide a [mre] that doesn't involve using it — especially since you haven't provided a sample input file.

Comment: i pull in an array of names for the directories using py excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pyexcel part of this has nothing to do with the problem, and there's a lot of needless strings, I'll give you the minimal code to answer your question, but it's up to you to incorporate it into your own program.

First, why not just read the data from `fpath` in as `folders` instead of using `data` as an intermediate?

Second, I don't see why you're only creating `folder` if `spath` already exists, i.e. if `os.mkdir()` gives an error. Python only executes the `except` if the `try` gives an error, so you'd have to run this program twice to create the directory structure you want.

Anyway, here's my minimal reproducible answer:

```
import os

pdir = 'C:\\Users\\mRotten\\target_dir'
folders = ['parent_1', 'parent_2', 'parent_3']
subfs = ['sub_1', 'sub_2', 'sub_3']

for f in folders:

    fpath = os.path.join(pdir, f)

    try: os.mkdir(fpath)
    except FileExistsError: pass

    subds = [os.path.join(fpath, sf) for sf in subfs]

    for sd in subds:
        try: os.mkdir(sd)
        except FileExistsError: pass
```

Comment: is there a way to create the folders with just the name instead of like this: ['Company ABC']

Comment: @rstowe1 Yep, same way you did it before.